# Spring Security overriding our custom login page in Staging & Production environment

Tags: spring, grails, authentication, spring-security

We have created our custom login page that requires more information than just the username & password using `spring-security-core:3.0.4` & `spring-security-ui:3.0.0.M2` plugins. And it is working perfectly in our `DEVELOPMENT` environment.

However, it is NOT working in `STAGING` and `PRODUCTION` environments. Somehow, Spring Security's default login page is overriding our custom page (not sure how this is even happening!).

Our **urlMappings.groovy**

```
"/login" (controller: 'login', action: 'auth')
```

In the **application.groovy** file we have...

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.errorPage = null
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/postLoginIndex'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = '/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false

grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
  [pattern: '/**/register/**',    access:['permitAll']],
  [pattern: '/**/login/**',    access:['permitAll']]  //we know it's not required, but just trying to see if this helps
]
```

And only handling database stuff in the environments settings part...

```
environments {
  development {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "create-drop"
      url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8888/postgres"
      username = "username"
      password = "password"
    }
  }
  staging {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update"
      url = System.getenv("DB_URL")
      username = System.getenv("DB_USER")
      password = System.getenv("DB_PASS")
    }
  }
  production {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update"
      url = System.getenv("DB_URL")
      username = System.getenv("DB_USER")
      password = System.getenv("DB_PASS")
    }
  }
}
```

So **how & why** our custom login page is getting replaced by Spring Security's default page in `STAGING` & `PRODUCTION` environments is making us very confused. Can anyone please help us?? Thank you!!!

Comment: `Security's default login page is overriding our custom page` then highly unlikely to be DB config related :). Possibly due to permission accessing custom pages on those environments.  Suggest you enable spring security logging and run it in least traffic related environemnt aka stage and send a request to see what debug offers back compare that against dev

Comment: Sorry, i actually meant to say that we r only handling database stuff in the environment settings, nothing else. Thank you for your suggestion, I'll pass that on to my team-mates and we will give it a try.